# How to Find value of Early voltage of output characteristic curve of BJT?

Tags: mosfet, bjt

I have this graph from data that I have. This is the output characteristic curve of BJT.
I want to find the value of early voltage VA?

[image]

Comment: Do you know the DEFINITION of the Early voltage?

Comment: @LvW the point where all lines meet on the negative axis of Vce.

Comment: @LvW I have Chosen the curve at 6mA, and then I plotted the linear portion of it, I found then the equation of the line then I calculated the intercept, but I'm not sure if this correct.

Comment: AMH9, from the set of curves I deduce that you have VBE as a parameter and NOT IB (because of unequal space between the lines). Is this correct? If yes - you are NOT allowed to determinme the Early voltage as described because this procedure works only if IB is the paramer.

Comment: It should work either way. There are an infinite number of traces you could draw and they ALL intercept the X axis at the Early voltage. Which subset you choose to draw is irrelevant.

Comment: It is not the NUMBER of traces which matters but the SLOPE of each trace. And the slope of the traces with VBE as parameter differs from the slope with IB as parameter. Only the latter allow determination of the Early voltage!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early voltage: -

[image]

It should be fairly easy to plot back the curves and see if they intercept as Mr. Early predicted

Comment: It should be noted that the above set of curves has IB as parameter (this is a "must" for finding the Early voltage).